# Find all occurrences in string containing HTML

Tags: html, r, regex, string

I have a string containing HTML like:

```
s <- "...<span class=\"pull-right\">170 cm</span>...
<span class=\"pull-right\">29</span>...
<span class=\"pull-right\">06/24/1987</span>..."
```

in which `...` means there are other HTML tags in between. I wanna extract the information between `>` and `</span>` which can be

- only digits
- digits and characters (uppercase or lowercase or both)
- date of the form `mm/dd/yyyy`

I came up with something like this for the regex:

```
">[0-9/]*[a-z ]*[A-Z]*</span>"
```

Is this correct? How can I extract the values of interest? That is, given `s`:

```
170 cm
29
06/24/1987
```

Comment: why aren't you using XML tools to extract data from XML (HTML) tags?

Comment: What have you researched w/r/t HTML scraping, then? This feels alot like "write this code for me for free".

Comment: @989 Look at BeautifulSoup4 for a more high-level approach. It goes great with `requests` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better go for an HTML parser. But if you need a quick and dirty regex-based solution, use lookarounds to extract a pattern between some opening (`(?<=>)` for preceding  `>`) and closing (`(?=</span>)` for trailing `</span>`) patterns:

```
(?<=>)[0-9/A-Za-z ]*(?=</span>)
```

Please note the `0-9/`, `a-z`, `A-Z` are combined in one class, otherwise strings like `1 Gb` won't match (your original regex requires uppercase letters follow lowercase ones).

The lookarounds are available with `perl=TRUE`:

```
m <- gregexpr("(?<=>)[0-9A-Za-z /]*(?=</span>)", s, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(s, m)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/yvXIuP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that matches

170 cm

29

06/24/1987

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})|(\d+ [A-Za-z]+)|(\d+)
```